# there is problem for python googletrans utf-8 side

Tags: python, utf-8, translate

```py
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()
translation = translator.translate("Hello friends", src="en", dest='tr')

print(translation.text)
```

output:

```
Merhaba arkadaÅŸlar
```

But it was supposed to be "**Merhaba arkadaşlar**" not "**Merhaba arkadaÅŸlar**". I'm trying to apply utf-8 to the output but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked this directly using the API thru `cmd` it does translate it correctly. There was a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67980704) posted on this before (linked from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55796793/python-googletrans-encoding-weird-chars)), which I believe to be what you might be seeing. Perhaps you may need to update the installed module or try the option to use [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

This is the result from the `curl` request thru `cmd`:

```
{
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "Merhaba arkadaşlar"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```